# can i use a javascirpt to reload webpage with two conditions

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I want to reload the webpage with confirm form resubmission and only if these two conditions:

- the web page is completely loaded and the document title still affaching = 504 Gateway Time-out

so I need a script for that: waiting for the page until it is completely loaded, after that the document title still = 504 Gateway Time-out the reload the page with confirm form resubmission

**if (document.title == '504 Gateway Time-out' && "document.readyState === "complete"")
{setTimeout(function() {window.location.reload(true);},}** i have this script but i dont know if it work correctly

Comment: If the page is fully loaded and a 504 was returned, then you usually can not use any JS code

Comment: so i cant realod page with a script code  if 504 was retured ?

Comment: Only if you can control the 504 page that your webserver generates

Comment: Why not check for the underlying problem instead? Why does your website generate a 504 error?

Comment: @NicoHaase the website generate 504 error because of overload on the website.so i need a script keep reloading page if the 504 erro appear and keep reloading after the webpage stoped

Comment: Why not resolve the problem properly? If your server is overloaded, check **why** this happens. This is a way better solution than overloading it further by sending the request multiple times

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

The following can be used to ensure the page document has fully loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { your code here }
```

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

From here you can put your if statement into this function checking the document title and doing what you want to do.

> i have this script but i dont know if it work correctly

Have you tested your code to see if it works correctly? Use the console in the developer tool for any javascript errors? Console logging if needed for debugging?

Good luck and hope this helps. If it does please mark that ^ arrow and ✅

Comment: hello .thank you for for the response. i wloud like to know if this statement of this code is corrrect to do what i want :     if (document.title == '504 Gateway Time-out' && "document.readyState === "complete"") {setTimeout(function() {window.location.reload(true);},}                                                                                                                i cant write a code beacause i dont know any thing is javascripts or any other languages . i juste need a code to run it on tampermonkey

Comment: @sizo All that will happen is the page will reload and keep reloading so in fact, this code is not good code. It might be malicious or even crash your website.

Comment: yes i need it to keep reloading the webpage until the error 504 disappear